# Angular 2 radio button validation

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular2-forms, angular7

I am trying to validate radio buttons in angular 2 by temmplate driven  but not working.I have searched in google also no one answered properly.Any genius can answer this question?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpyekb?file=src/app/app.component.html

app.component.html

```
 <form #f="ngForm"> 
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
<div class="radio">
<input type="radio"
           name="radio"
           id="radio-{{option.id}}"
           [(ngModel)]="value"
           [value]="option.value"/> 
    <label for="radio-{{option.id}}">{{option.id}}
    </label> 
 </div>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="f.submitted">Please select</div>

 <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio"
               name="radio"
               id="radio-{{option.id}}"
               [(ngModel)]="value"
               [value]="option.value"
               required

               /> 
        <label for="radio-{{option.id}}">{{option.id}}
        </label> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !f.valid">Please select</div>


May be you are looking for the above validation. If not can you please help to know what exactly you are looking for ?
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply..If i use only one radio button inside the form your code will work perfetcly but if i use more textbox and checkbox inside the form your code will not support because u have used !f.valid this is validation for common.

Comment: Can you provide me a link in which you have all the stuff and require validation so that I can provide solution to that

Comment: Exactly what i want see my original code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-component-validation-qiyqsd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I have created custom radio button component and checkbox then i am trying to validate using angular 2 template driven validation